# Sum of $n$ relative risk ratios and Poisson regression

Tags: inference, poisson-regression, odds-ratio, contingency-tables, relative-risk

Consider $n$ joint PMF defined by two Bernoulli r.v. $X_i$ and $Y$. The probability $P(X_i, Y)$ is estimated as:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
& Y = 1 & Y = 0 \\
\hline
X_i = 1 & \frac{a_i}{a_i + b_i} & \frac{b_i}{a_i + b_i} \\
X_i = 0 & \frac{c_i}{c_i + d_i} & \frac{d_i}{c_i + d_i}
\end{array}$$

Then the relative risk is $RR_i = \frac{P(Y = 1 \mid X_i = 1)}{P(Y = 1 \mid X_i = 0)}$.

I want to interpret or see better the connection between the different $RR_i$ and Poisson regression: $$\log(E[Y \mid X]) = \beta_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n\beta_ix_i\,,$$ where $Y \mid X \sim \text{Poiss}(\lambda)$.

**Background:** I am given $RR_1, \dots, RR_n$ and $\sum_i\log(RR_i)$. The sum and $\log(RR_i)$ should be approximately normally distributed. I am wondering whether a better interpretation of $R_i$ is possible by connecting it to $\beta_i$.